# Automated way to move text from Excel to Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a word document that has a specific template. I would like an automated way to copy specific values from an Excel spreadsheet to specific places of the word document. 
Is this possible?

Example

**Excel**

```
A1: 100
A2: 200
```

**Word:**

```
bla bla {A1} bla bla {A2}.
```

So every time I change A1 and A2 cells the word document changes also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371442/reference-excel-cells-in-word

Comment: You could possibly use the Mail Merge option in Word, I'm not an expert with this but it gives you the ability to create something like this, however if you change the fiels in excel, you would have to re-run the mailmerge for it to re-insert the new fields. Mate's linked solution may be better!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Both Word and Excel Files
2. Copy the required Cell in Excel
3. In Word Document go to the area where Cell Value is to be placed
4. Select Paste Special.
5. Select PASTE LINK Button
6. Select AS UNFORMATTED TEXT Option
7. Press OK Button, to get the desired output.

I learnt from K2, so credit goes to K2.